# Trying to get Key given the Value From Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array thus (got this using `var_dump`):

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'post_id' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'post_id' => string '9' (length=1)
```

I want to get the key when I have just the `post_id`. For example, I want '0' returned if I have '6' and '1' if I have '9'. I have tried:

```
$key = array_keys($subs, array_keys($subs[??], 6));
```

given that the `$subs` is the array. The issue is, I don't know how to iterate through the array 'within' the 'parent' array, hence, the '??'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `array_filter()` and `use` to do this. Like this:

```
$array; // your array
$needle; // the value you are looking for
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function ($element) use ($needle) {
    return ($element['post_id'] === $needle);
});

$matching_keys = array_keys($filtered_array);
```

The `array_filter()` will filter down the input array to only those array element arrays that have a value for `post_id` that matches the value of `$needle`.  You can use `array_keys` to get the key values for the remaining element(s) after the filter has been applied.

Comment: I keep getting empty arrays, for all arrays save $array. :s

Comment: @iroegbu just make sure and check the conditional if you are longer for a string value representation of an integer in your key and using an actual integer for your needle, this would return false for the comparison. You might need to use `==` for comparison in such a case. Try dumping `$element` and `$needle` inside the filter function to see what you are actually comparing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$post_id_to_find = '6';
$key = '';
foreach ($subs as $k1 => $v1)
{
    foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2)
    {
        if ($post_id_to_find == $v2)
        {
            $key = $k1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially what this code does is loop through the outer array and for each element loop through inner array, and if it finds the post id you want it'll set a variable that was initalized outside of the loops so after you break out of the loops you'll have the appropriate key.

---

**EDIT**

This is actually a pretty crappy answer, I realized you don't really need the inner loop since you know what key you want to check in the inner arrays... Anyway it seems like you used another answer, so this is pretty much moot.

Comment: this returns the key of the inner array, I need the key of the outer array

Comment: Please include some explanation of your answer rather than posting code only.

Comment: @iroegbu replace his `$key = $k2;` with `$key = $k1;` to get the outer array key.